# Database with FILESTREAM enabled gives Error 3056 during backup

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I have a SQL 2014 database enabled for FILESTREAM and I am getting errors 3056 during backup.

The message is

DESCRIPTION:    The backup operation has detected an unexpected file in a FILESTREAM container. The backup operation will continue and include file 'F:\Resources\Staff pictures\Outlook\xxx.jpg'.

Any ideas on how to resolve this greatly appreciated.

Regards

James

Answer (score 2):

You have manually create a file in a FS container. Stop doing so.

A FS container is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg471497.aspx):

> FILESTREAM data must be stored in FILESTREAM filegroups. A FILESTREAM
>   filegroup is a special filegroup that contains file system directories
>   instead of the files themselves. These file system directories are
>   called data containers. Data containers are the interface between
>   Database Engine storage and file system storage.

As you see, is nothing but a file system folder. Do not delete or create files in these folder, is simple as that. all interaction must occur via the FILESTREAM API.

Comment: The backup operation has as the error messages implies added the unwanted file to the backup. Grab the file and insert it through the filestream api go get rid of the error message.